# Multiple monitor mirrored as default

Tags: 14.04, monitor

I've a laptop with intel graphic card and at home I connect it on an external monitor.
Is there a way to have monitors mirrored by default?
Now every time I boot I've to re-configure in this way.

thanks!

Answer (score 5):

#### 1. Clean and simple

I think the cleanest and easiest would be to:

1. Find out both screen names with the help of `xrandr` (look for the string "connected")
2. Open System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

   ```
   xrandr --output <screen_name1> --auto --same-as <screen_name2>
   ```

   To a key combination of your choice.

That way you would only have to press the key combination to activate mirrored screens.

#### 2. Without having to look up the screen name

A bit more sophisticated would be to do the same, but let a script find out both screen names:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", "xrandr"]).decode("utf-8").split()
connected = [output[i-1] for i in range(len(output)) if output[i] == "connected"]
command = "xrandr --output "+connected[0]+" --auto --same-as "+connected[1]
subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", command])
```

Save the script as `mirror.py`, run it by the command:

```
python3 /path/to/mirror.py
```

under a key combination, like in the first option.

#### 3.Fully automatically

If you want it all done without any action from your side, run the script below in the background. It checks every 5 seconds if a second monitor is connected and sets it to mirrored if so.

*The script*

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time

def screens():
    output = subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", "xrandr"]).decode("utf-8").split()
    return [output[i-1] for i in range(len(output)) if output[i] == "connected"]

todo = True

while True:
    scr = screens()
    if len(scr) == 2 and todo == True:
        command = "xrandr --output "+scr[0]+" --auto --same-as "+scr[1]
        subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", command])
        todo = False
    elif len(scr) == 1 and todo == False:
        todo = True
    time.sleep(5)
```

*How to use*

- Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `mirror_screen.py`
- Test it by restarting your laptop (screen disconnected)
- Run the script by the command:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/mirror_screen.py
  ```
- Connect the second monitor to see if it automatically switches to mirrored.
- If all works fine, add the command (above) to your startup applications:
   
  Dash > Startup Applications > Add

Comment: @arrubiu Did you run into any problems using the answer?

Comment: Superb. :). Long time painpoint resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In 22.04 (no idea how far back this goes):

```
gsettings set com.canonical.unity.settings-daemon.plugins.xrandr default-monitors-setup clone
```

For other options on this setting:

```
gsettings describe com.canonical.unity.settings-daemon.plugins.xrandr default-monitors-setup
```

(this setting is hopefully in the GUI somewhere, but I don't know where)